# C# error message "Property can not be assigned to -- it is read only."

Tags: c#, properties, readonly

Read only properties can be assigned in a constructor. But when I try to explicitly implement get method, compiler shows an error (Property cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.) Can I implement getter or it's supposed to be without implementation?

```
public class PersonalIncome 
{
    private decimal _anualRate;
    public decimal AnualRate
    {
        get { return _anualRate != 0 ? _anualRate : 40_000;  }
    }

    public PersonalIncome(decimal paymentRate)
    {
        switch (paymentRate)
        {
            case var rate when (rate > 300):
                AnualRate = rate; // **Property can not be assigned to -- it is read only.**
                break;
            default:
              break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `_anualRate = rate;`

Comment: There´s no such thing as a readonly-property. What you mean is a property with a readonly backing-field.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I keep reading your comment and scratching my head.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I think he means auto-properties like  `public int Property {get;}`

Comment: If you coded up `AnualRate` (which, by the way, is spelled wrong) as a read-only auto-property, it would be settable in the constructor.  But, in your case, you have a backing field.  How would the compiler know that if you set `AnualRate` in the constructor, you really wanted to set `_anualRate`?  Either set `_anualRate` directly, or add a private setter that sets it (I think I'd do the latter, but that's just me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the getter, but then you can only assign values to the backing field directly:

```
_anualRate = rate;
```

Once you decide against using the convenience of the auto-property, you have to do everything by yourself.

Comment: I figured that out as well, but still wondering why I can use it with automatic getters, (using property name), but when implementing get method, I have to use field name. Feels inconsistent for me.

Comment: @Pavel the property you have does not define a `set`, thats why you cannot "set" it to anything.  If you want the property to only be set privately (i.e in the class), you can make your property have a `private set { }`

Comment: @maccettura Well, in case of a property with only a getter you *can* assign a value in the constructor (C#6). See my answer.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Not when a `get` body is defined (which is why OP has this problem)

Comment: @maccettura,
Your suggestion works only if set method is also implemented.
private set { _anualRate = value; }
Otherwise, it does not assign anything to a related private field. But that's a vaild solution as well. Thank you.

Comment: @Pavel I know, thats why my comment has `{ }` in it, it implies you need to set the body

Answer (score 1):

Your class could be rewritten like this:

```
public class PersonalIncome
{
    public decimal AnualRate { get; private set; }

    public PersonalIncome(decimal paymentRate)
    {
        AnualRate = paymentRate > 300 ? paymentRate : 40_000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You refer to a property with a `readonly` backing-field.

That´s exactly what the compiler also generates from C#6 upwards when using an auto-implemented property with a default-value:

```
int MyProperty { get; } = -1;
```

This will be translated to the following:

```
readonly int _myProperty = -1;
int MyProperty { get { return this._myProperty; } }
```

Now the compiler replaces every call to your property by the backing-field. However this only works for auto-properties that do not have a body defined. In your case you already have one, which is why the compiler can´t replace that one. As a property itself is nothing but a get- and a set-method, what you want to do is the following, which is obvious non-sense:

```
int get_MyProperty() { return this._MyProperty; }
...
this.get_MyProperty() = 1;
```

The reason this works for an auto-property is that the compiler knows how to replace the call to the property. However suppose your own getter was more complex:

```
get
{
    DoSomething();
    return this._myProperty + 5;
}
```

Now the compiler can´t replace the call to the property.

So the only way to have your own get-implementation tigether with a property which is get-only, is to use the backing-field:

```
this._myProperty = 1;
```

Comment: I believe that's the official name in C#6 - Read-only auto-properties
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#read-only-auto-properties